# How to draw a lineString in Openlayers6

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I have a map that uses a WMTS source and is using EPSG:25832 for the projection.
I do not understand why it is so difficult for me to add a line between the 2 markers.
It should be a line with multiple coordinates but I cant find any documentation on how to add a line.
I am assuming that it should be a new vectorLayer with a lineString I will be adding, but the documentation is so hard to understand. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I have been looking at this example, but I don't think it is very clear what is going on. And I will be using data, not allowing the user to draw the line.

```
var map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            opacity: 0.7,
            source: new WMTS({
                crossOrigin: 'Anonymous',
                url: `https://kortforsyningen.kms.dk/topo_skaermkort_daempet?TICKET=${TOKEN}`,
                layer: 'dtk_skaermkort_daempet',
                matrixSet: 'View1',
                format: 'image/jpeg',
                tileGrid: tileGrid,
                style: 'default',
                size: SIZE
            })
        }),
        new VectorLayer({
            source: new VectorSource({
                features: [originMarker]
            }),
            style: new Style({
                image: new Icon({
                    anchor: [0.5, 1],
                    src: A_ICON,
                })
            })
        }),
        new VectorLayer({
            source: new VectorSource({
                features: [destinationMarker]
            }),
            style: new Style({
                image: new Icon({
                    anchor: [0.5, 1],
                    src: B_ICON,
                })
            })
        })
    ],
    view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat(centerPoint, 'EPSG:25832'),
        zoom: 3,
        resolutions: tileGrid.getResolutions(),
        projection: projection,
        extent: EXTENT
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a LineString feature joining two Point features

```
new Feature(new LineString([
  originMarker.getGeometry().getCoordinates(),
  destination.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
]))
```

then add it to a new layer, or to an existing vector source.

Comment: Is that for a line with only 2 points? I need to add a line with many coordinates, can LineString handle that?

Comment: Thank you. I find the documentation of OpenLayers to be very hard to understand. Of all the projects I've worked with, this has got to be the steepest learning curve by far.